# What is the expected number of steps a particle will take to reach $10$ for the first time?

Tags: probability, number-theory, contest-math

> Consider integers ${1,2,...,10}$. A particle is initially at $1$. It moves to an adjacent integer in the next step. What is the expected number of steps it will take to reach $10$ for the first time?

When the particle is at $1$, it can only move to $2$ since there's no $0$. But from $2$, you can either move to $1$ or $3$ with $50%$ of probability and so on. Clearly making a tree diagram will take a long time, but I'm not sure how to approach this more mathematically.

Comment: Work it by backwards induction.  Let $E_i$ be the expected amount of time it takes if you are at $i$ (so the answer is $E_1$).  Then, for example, $E_{10}=0$, $E_1=E_2+1$ and for $2≤i≤9$ we have $E_i=\frac 12\times (E_{i-1}+E_{i+1})+1$

Comment: @lulu — how can you get that formula $E_i=\frac{1}{2}×(E_i−1+E_i+1)+1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_n$ be the location of the particle at time $n$, then $\{X_n:n=0,1,\ldots\}$ is a Markov chain on $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ with transition probabilities
$$
P_{ij} =\begin{cases}
1,& (i,j)=(0,1)\text{ or } (i,j) = (10,10)\\
p,& j=i+1, 2\leqslant i\leqslant 9\\
1-p,& j=i-1, 2\leqslant i\leqslant 8\\
0,& \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here we allow $10$ to be an absorbing state for convenience. Let 
$$
E_i = \inf\{n>0: X_n=10\mid X_0=i\}
$$
for $1\leqslant i\leqslant 10$ (trivially, $E_{10}=0$ with probability $1$). This gives the linear system of equations
\begin{align}
E_1 &= 1+E_2\\
E_i &= 1 + (1-p)E_{i-1} + pE_{i+1},\ 2\leqslant i\leqslant 9,
\end{align}
and solving these yields
$$
E_1 = \frac2{p^8}(1 - 6 p + 17 p^2 - 28 p^3 + 30 p^4 - 20 p^5 + 10 p^6 + p^8).
$$
When $p=\frac12$, we have $E_1 = 82$.